# Stop current running Spring boot in linux

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am running a springboot application in linux.To run this springboot we use below command.

```
java -jar sssup-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

This spring boot application makes an endpoint available which is then used by other services.

Now when the new version of .jar is available i have to stop the current running .jar and again run the above mentioned command.

Here my question is how to stop the current running sssup-SNAPSHOT.jar ?

Comment: You can kill the process using `kill <PID>` command. To find the process id fire `ps -ef | grep "sssup-SNAPSHOT.jar"`

Comment: @Saurabh is right...just send a SIGKILL to this process

Comment: You will have to find out the port number on which your java is working, you can find that in application.properties or application.yaml. if not declared then its 8080 port. Next you will have to find the process on which it is running lsof -t -i:8080. kill the process.

Comment: @Saurabh Please post your answer as an actual answer.

Comment: @MalavShah Please post your answer as an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You kind find the PID of the spring process and send a SIGTERM signal to it.

Find the PID (Here the PID is 12345)

```sh
$ ps -ef | grep sssup | awk '{print $2}'
12345
```

Send a kill signal (This will send the signal SIGTERM)

```sh
kill 12345
```

If the application handles the SIGTERM gracefully, you can force kill it by sending SIGKILL

```sh
kill -s SIGKILL 12345
### or
kill -9 12345
```

Signals are documented here
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

You can list signals and their numbers by running

```sh
kill -l
```

EDIT: Onliner

```sh
ps -ef | grep "sssup-SNAPSHO[T]" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you are running the process in the background you need to find its process first to kill it.

To find the process ID fire below command:

```
ps -ef | grep "sssup-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

The output will look something like below:

```
 502  5980  5964   0 10:40AM ttys000
```

Your second column is your process ID So, over here it is `5980`. After copying that fire below command.

```
kill 5980
```

Just check again by firing `ps -ef` command that it gets killed or not. If it's not killed already than you can use `-9` flag to `force kill` it. Like `kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: This is clearly a better way. Not sure why this answer wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to bring the background process to the foreground with the `fg` command and then press Ctrl+C. This will only work if you are in the same terminal where you ran the JAR file.

Another more reliable way is to use `ps -a | grep java` to find the process id of your app. Then you can do `kill <PID>` with that process id.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do maually then do below steps

```
1. open terminal 
2. type JPS and enter
3. copy your application process id
4. sudo kill -9 application_id
```

If JPS is not avilable then

```
1. open terminal
2. type ps -a | grep sssup-SNAPSHOT.jar
3. copy you process id
4. do sudo kill -9 processid
```

If you want to do via Shell script use below

```
app_id=$(ps -ef | grep 'sssup-SNAPSHOT.jar' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ printf $2 }')
sudo kill $app_id
echo Killed Application and Starting New
nohup java -jar "sssup-SNAPSHOT.jar" &
```

Comment: why nohup you used to run .jar ?

Comment: you can remove nohup.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot print's the process id in the log (Number after `INFO` in log) then use command `kill -9 pid`

`Note`: `9` means the process will be killed by the kernel; this signal cannot be ignored.